# Guice Merge Collection between AbstractModules

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, guice, guice-3

I have a couple modules

```
 A extends AbstractModule

 B extends AbstractModule
```

Which are used to provide class C.

```
 class C {

    @Inject List<Components> components;
 }
```

That class C can use A, B or both to be instantiate with a specific information.

For now I have a provider on A module

```
 @Provider
 List<Components>
```

Of course I can only have one provider per context, so only A can have it so far. But I need on both because everyone generate his own Components.

I´ve been reading about Multibinders  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

But I would like to know before go for a guice extension, if the guice core provide a mechanism for what I want to do.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Use multibindings. This is exactly what they’re for.